# Would Osprey Farpoint-40 rucksack fit (onto laptop sleeve) 17 inch laptop?

Tags: luggage, backpacks

I have done some reading around different rucksacks pros and cons and now considering on buying [Osprey Farpoint 40](http://www.ospreyeurope.com/gb_en/travel-carry/farpoint-series/farpoint-40-14).

[image]

The only thing that keeps bothering me is, I am not sure if it will fit my 17'' inch laptop (Alienware 17). Since this is quite a common rucksack I was wondering if anyone has tried to shove one into the sleeve before me, and what her experiences were.

**Would Osprey Farpoint-40 rucksack fit 17 inch laptop?**

Comment: if you have a laptop that cool, just carry it around in the open!

Comment: @JoeBlow I do, it's just that I am not allowed to do that on a plane :) if not for stupid regulations I would never put it away... I also like to go around and ask people if they know what Alienware is, most of them don't - so I have to explain to them how this is top tear machine and like show it and tell them how expensive it is, and how it makes me super cool and such... :) most people smile so them must like me very much...

Comment: LOL sounds good.  just for the record.  you probably already do this but: i also pop my laptop in a protective sleeve (just one of those $10 neoprene-whatever sleeves.  (there's one laying on the floor here and the brand is "in-case" - it has a heavy velour protective interior.)  only then would I put a laptop in a backpack.  I think it's a good idea - something to consider!

Comment: it's ridiculous that they now seem to charge like $50+ for a padded sleeve that costs 30 cents wholesale .. https://www.incase.com/shop/sleeves/icon-sleeve-mb-retina-15/graylumen/ it looks like fortunately you can still get the same thing made in the same factory with no logo for <$10 ... https://www.amazon.com/dp/B011J4C66G.  Again just one man's opinion, your laptop "sleeve" is more important for extreme travel than the pack as such!  happy trails!

Comment: No, it will not. These bags are designed for "normal" laptops, and not for the souped up gamer versions. For best results, try searching for a bag advertising fitting 18" laptops.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I wouldn't be so sure, I managed to put it in this bag and it's designed for 15.4' http://www.ebuyer.com/192046-wenger-cobalt-backpack-w-600629?mkwid=suIl9nmam_dc&pcrid=51508045379&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=CMqhnZ2ew88CFYYV0wodI4IC3g what gives me even more hope is that  Farpoint-40 sleeve is 14h x 11w x 1.5d and http://www.mobileedge.com/alienware-vindicator-backpack-17.html is 16.3" x 11.8" x 1.9" which comes 0.8 in and 0.4 in too much which isn't that much.....

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius the problem is in the first numbers: the 14h and the 16.3". Also, from bitter experience, even the 0.4 and much more a 0.8" is enough to cause grief.

Comment: @chx 1st number is only limited by zipper on the bag, I mean I don't mind if laptop is sticking out of the sleeve, if zipper is close to sleeve then indeed this might turn out to be a problem. I agree that 0.8 might be too much.... :) I am now planning on driving to Canterbury ~30 miles, there should be a shop that has this bag.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR; It Does**

This was begging for an experiment,...

So I bought Alienware 17 R2 and Osprey Farpoint 40 and the rest is history...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnrUfZVdJog

And if it fits Alienware 17 it pretty much should fit any 17'' laptop...

Comment: Careful there. http://imgur.com/sjtq4Gc you are going to ruin the zipper pretty quick. It shows the corner of the laptop poking at it.

Answer (score 2):

This [review](http://www.nomadtravelbags.com/osprey-farpoint-40-travel-backpack-review/) claims

> A laptop pocket will handle up to a 17” laptop

I saw similar claims on the Amazon product page. But the [manual](http://www.ospreypacks.com/user_manuals/OM_Farpoint_S16_ENG.pdf) claims the laptop sleeve to be

> Inches 14h x 11w x 1.5d

which in theory could house a 17" screen since it's 17.8" diagonally but real world 17" laptops are 16" or above in height with a 11" width.

The Alienware 17 however is 17.9 x 12.9 x 2.26-2.23 inches which is far, far bigger than this size. This old [CNN review](https://www.cnet.com/products/alienware-17-gaming-laptop-computer/review/) concedes it's closer to a 18" laptop in fact:

> the Alienware 17 desktop replacement gaming laptop is not all that much smaller than the 18-inch Alienware 18version we recently reviewed